# Expander menu in C #

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, panel

I am trying to reproduce the operation of the `Control Expander WPF`, or as shown in the menu of  `Outlook`, `Vertical Web Menu` etc., since in  `WindowsForms` this control does not exist. Here I leave the [sample code: Menu_Expader.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gL9zhUVNUZb_aUhWxXxbkgOdJsGIs1RY/view?usp=sharing) link **GoogleDrive**.

**I have managed to do it using the following controls:**

- `Panels`
- `FlowLayoutPanel`
- `1 Time Control`
- `Button Vectors`
- `Labels Vectors` ...

> **This works perfectly**, but it happens that to each panel I must establish a
> `Maximum Size` and `Minimum Size` therefore every time I add an `item` inside I must modify the size of the panel where I add it, and the `item` are very close to each other is a bit annoying for the user's vision.

**Example this is what I currently have:**

[image]

#### EDIT

**Code Sample:**

```
    // The state of an expanding or collapsing panel.
    private enum ExpandState
    {
        Expanded,
        Expanding,
        Collapsing,
        Collapsed,
    }

    // The expanding panels' current states.
    private ExpandState[] ExpandStates;

    // The Panels to expand and collapse.
    private Panel[] ExpandPanels;

    // The expand/collapse buttons.
    private Button[] ExpandButtons;

    // Initialize.
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the arrays.
        ExpandStates = new ExpandState[]
        {
            ExpandState.Expanded,
            ExpandState.Expanded,
            ExpandState.Expanded,
        };
        ExpandPanels = new Panel[]
        {
            panModule1,
            panModule2,
            panModule3,
        };
        ExpandButtons = new Button[]
        {
            btnExpand1,
            btnExpand2,
            btnExpand3,
        };

        // Set expander button Tag properties to give indexes
        // into these arrays and display expanded images.
        for (int i = 0; i < ExpandButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            ExpandButtons[i].Tag = i;
            ExpandButtons[i].Image = Properties.Resources.expander_down;
        }
    }

    // Start expanding.
    private void btnExpander_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the button.
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        int index = (int)btn.Tag;

        // Get this panel's current expand
        //  state and set its new state.
        ExpandState old_state = ExpandStates[index];
        if ((old_state == ExpandState.Collapsed) ||
            (old_state == ExpandState.Collapsing))
        {
            // Was collapsed/collapsing. Start expanding.
            ExpandStates[index] = ExpandState.Expanding;
            ExpandButtons[index].Image = Properties.Resources.expander_up;
        }
        else
        {
            // Was expanded/expanding. Start collapsing.
            ExpandStates[index] = ExpandState.Collapsing;
            ExpandButtons[index].Image = Properties.Resources.expander_down;
        }

        // Make sure the timer is enabled.
        tmrExpand.Enabled = true;
    }

    // The number of pixels expanded per timer Tick.
    private const int ExpansionPerTick = 7;

    // Expand or collapse any panels that need it.
    private void tmrExpand_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Determines whether we need more adjustments.
        bool not_done = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < ExpandPanels.Length; i++)
        {
            // See if this panel needs adjustment.
            if (ExpandStates[i] == ExpandState.Expanding)
            {
                // Expand.
                Panel pan = ExpandPanels[i];
                int new_height = pan.Height + ExpansionPerTick;
                if (new_height >= pan.MaximumSize.Height)
                {
                    // This one is done.
                    new_height = pan.MaximumSize.Height;
                }
                else
                {
                    // This one is not done.
                    not_done = true;
                }

                // Set the new height.
                pan.Height = new_height;
            }
            else if (ExpandStates[i] == ExpandState.Collapsing)
            {
                // Collapse.
                Panel pan = ExpandPanels[i];
                int new_height = pan.Height - ExpansionPerTick;
                if (new_height <= pan.MinimumSize.Height)
                {
                    // This one is done.
                    new_height = pan.MinimumSize.Height;
                }
                else
                {
                    // This one is not done.
                    not_done = true;
                }

                // Set the new height.
                pan.Height = new_height;
            }
        }

        // If we are done, disable the timer.
        tmrExpand.Enabled = not_done;
    }
```

**I want to get a result similar to this - Bootstrap Menu Accordion:**

[image]

> Imitate that operation **panels expand according to the `quantity` of `item` that it contains** as long as it does not protrude from the screen, in which case it will show the `scroll bar`. I know there are software that provide custom controls like `DVexpress`, `DotNetBar Suite` among others, but they are `Licensed Software` I do not want to use it illegally `pirate`. **Can you help me optimize it or create it in another way?**

Environment: Visual Studio 2010 & .NET NetFramework 4.

> The [original question](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130384/69447) I made it in StackOverFlow in Spanish.

- Modulo (Module)
- Menu Principal (Main menu)
- Mantenimientos (Maintenance)
- Procesos (Processes)
- Consultas (Queries)
- Reportes (Reports)

**Note:** If someone speaks Spanish and English and can do a better translation, please edit the question. (Excuse the advertising on the image, I recorded the screen with a software trial version).

Comment: Your labels are set to autosize, set it manually and you will able to get more distance between them in the lists. Obviously the panels gain scrollbars, which means the recalculcating of their size does not work. You can try to make your own panel subclass that can do that itself.

Comment: `You can try to make your own panel subclass that can do that itself` I do not know how to do that, can you provide an example?. Take a look I have edited the question adding the example code and please if you can edit the question to make it more understandable and clear for all users, I would be grateful, as it may contain grammatical errors and may qualify negative.